# How to structure complex Django project?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project which is getting more and more complex. I started off with the traditional files: models, views, and forms.py. The issue I have right now is that those files are getting bigger and bigger and I'd like to break them into manageable parts. What are the best practices around that?

In addition, I am wondering if it is best practice to add class method to a model in Django? For instance, I have a Vote class on which I would like to add methods to get the number of votes for a specific user, content, etc?

Comment: The official Django advice seems to be "use Managers" but read blog posts about it; I find class methods more convenient

Comment: @agf I concur - I have yet to find it worth the trouble of a manager, especially given that one can factor out class methods into base classes.

Comment: Where can I find an example of this? What about the number of views and forms which all end up in their own file?

Comment: I use managers ALL the time to keep the logic in the views down to a minimum.  A Vote.objects.by_user(user) is a simple way to express what becomes a filter that exposes model members.

Comment: @Mark0978 that's a perfect example of a good use for a manager. Frankly, I think it's very basic -- logic about recordsets or retrieving/creating records goes in a manager. Logic about altering a record or extracting information/related records goes in a class method. Utility methods that assist views or models goes in utils. Logic around validation, saving a record from a form, or making calculations based on form entries goes in the form class. Display logic goes in templates.

Comment: @Jordan So far, I don't see anything we disagree on.  I'm assuming if he doesn't know how to use Managers, it might be that he needs know about them.  I would add that view code needs to be in the under 15 lines range and if it is longer than that, you have a refactor to do.

Comment: In the directory structure created by Django, where do put your Manager?

Comment: *sigh* I wish I could stick to the 15 line rule, but sometimes logic -- even refactored as much as I can -- just gets in the way. For example, if there are multiple forms and a fair amount of logic surrounding record inputs, etc.

Comment: Would you place the Managers in a separate file like a managers.py or keep them in models.py?

Comment: I always put the ModelManager right before the Model class.  See my answer below.  If you put them in another file you end up doing an import and it doesn't really help much.

Comment: @Mark0978: Do you have all your models inside the same file? Do you have one file per Manager/Model?

Comment: All my models and managers are in one file.  However I have multiple apps, and therefore multiple model files.  I try to break it along function guidelines, patients, studies, labs, documents... etc...  Each time the focus changes, I create a new app and then join the pieces together with foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find refactoring can really help. Are there a lot of similar views that just have different templates or querysets? Make a more generic view that accepts multiple template names, records, etc.

Anything that requires extensive calculations gets moved to a utils.py in the same directory.

Class methods are for actions that affect a single record; managers are for dealing with filtering records or creating a record.

If you're already taking the step of making separate `models`, `views`, etc. folders and breaking views and models into separate files, that suggests to me that you could separate them out into separate apps. I like that as an option much better.

Comment: I agree with Jordan. When models, views, and etc. get too big, that might be an indication that you can refactor them into separate apps.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly use class methods, and I have found that where there are similar operations to be performed on classes, it is possible (and easy) to factor the classmethods into base classes (use the `self` parameter of your class method to write generic code).

Probably the best way to manage broken-up views, etc is to replace each file you want to break up with its own package, and put whatever you need to (if anything) into that package's `__init__.py` module.

Answer (score 1):

On using model managers vs class methods.  doing it this way, your code is easier for others to read, and you can combine this kind of code with other filter/select_related/order_by.  Below is a simple example, but as the logic gets more complicated Managers make a great addition to your setup and for very little code, give you a lot of good connective tissue in your app.

I agree with Jordan that you may need more than one app and if you have a large code base now, the lines to break everything up by should be more apparent to.

```
class VoteManager(models.ModelManager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)
    def by_content(self, content)
        return self.filter(content=content)

class Vote(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
    ...
    objects = VoteManager()
```